# SharePoint lists created from Excel not working with Powerapps

Tags: powerapp

we're moving data from an old MySQL to SharePoint Online.
We used "export table" command in Excel to create the SharePoint lists, it worked fine but we're experincing an issue: the button "Customize with Powerapps" in new/edit forms is missing.
Anyway we found that we can edit PowerApp form from List Settings > Form Settings but when we click on new item tha standard SharePoint form is shown. It looks like a bug, we tried in different site collection and different tenants without any luck.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks
Maurizio